# how to print mysql_num_rows?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a database structure like this
[image]

and am trying to print the rows count 
but am getting  1 only

the code am using is

```
$sql="select Count(*) from uniqueviews where hour=13"; $result=mysql_query($sql); $ml=mysql_num_rows($result); echo $ml;
```

according to the query
it should print 6
but its printing 1

where am doing wrong ?

i think its counting the rows ?

how can i print the result after rows count ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Count(*)` only returns one row, containing the number of rows. That's why you get only `1` as return value. If you want the actual value, you can either do this:

```
$sql="select * from uniqueviews where hour=13"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql); 
$ml=mysql_num_rows($result); 
echo $ml;
```

or this:

```
$sql="select COUNT(*) from uniqueviews where hour=13"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql);  
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
$ml=$row[0];
echo $ml;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually printing the number of rows that your query has returned.since you are counting the result .You should use [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) instead to get the result of your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $result = select Count(*) from uniqueviews where hour=13 // $result is 6 here

 and when you use mysql_count_rows($result) it returns 1 which is correct

 try printing $result which should be 6
```

or you can replace **count(*)** by * from the query and it should give you the correct result

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something.

If you do `my_sql_num_rows($result)` it will display only the **total returned rows** and, in this logic, the result of only one row is totally correct (`count(*)` will return only a row).

If you want to keep that logic, don't use `count` into your sql query, just

```
SELECT * from uniqueviews where hour = 13
```

or if you want to keep that sql query, change the way of fetching result:

```
mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql    = "select Count(*) AS COUNT from uniqueviews where hour=13";
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
$count  = mysql_fetch_object($result);

echo $count->COUNT;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"select Count(*) from uniqueviews where hour=13"
```

This will only return the count ie only a single row ..

If you want to see the result of query ie total count

then do some thing like this

```
$sql="select Count(*) from uniqueviews where hour=13"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$ml=mysql_fetch_array($result); 
echo $ml[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

Num rows returned by your query is always 1, because there is only 1 record returned - record with count of rows from that select.

Replace:

```
$sql="select Count(*) from uniqueviews where hour=13";
```

With:

```
$sql="select id from uniqueviews where hour=13";
```

Then use mysql_num_rows.

But you should get value returned by count(), mysql_num_rows is not for operations like this.